# How to get all the items contained inside a office365 onedrive

Tags: onedrive, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get all the files and folders contained inside a office365 onedrive  folder in one rest API call, is there any option to do it?

Comment: Do you mean the [children of a specific folder](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/list.htm) or children of the folder, and all descendents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a specific API call to retrieve a flat representation of a Drive. You can achieve a similar effect however using the drive's [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search) method.

Simply pass an empty query string and it will return metadata for each file (regardless of it's directory):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='')`

Comment: I was trying out the search, one of the things I observed is that it gives inconsistent results, the drive had plenty of items that were recently uploaded but they were not getting listed as part of the search even after couple of minutes. For another drive they were getting listed.

Comment: when I do this it is just always empty! why might that be anyone know?

Comment: This does not work, as of 11-Jan-2020. It returns a status code 400 "invalid request" with the error message "Search Query cannot be empty."

Comment: This API almost does that, except it always misses some files, as if they were not indexed (even after waiting few days, they never get returned by the API, not sure why)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790157/microsoft-graph-api-is-it-possible-to-traverse-recursive-over-folders) is using Delta-Query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[DRIVEID]/root/delta
```

This works also for specific Item-Ids:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[DRIVEID]/items/[ITEM ID]/delta
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, try this search request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='%2A')
```

Or:

```
https://api.onedrive.com:443/v1.0/drives/(driveid)/items/(itemid)/view.search?q=%2A
```

Where ***%2A*** is asterisk, ***itemid*** may be a root folder id. Don't forget about pagination.

Or with OneDriveSDK:

```
_connection.SearchForItemsAsync(odFolder.ItemReference(), "*", ItemRetrievalOptions.Default)
```

Don't use "expand" query with search query.
This should return all items in current folder recursively - sub-folders, sub-items.

Comment: This solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Gabrielius probably this was changed by Microsoft. So, doesn't work anymore