# List all files recursively in microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive, office365api

We are trying to retrieve all files under a folder recursively, but I can't find an API for that.

I've tried using the search API without a query, but this doesn't return anything.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root/search(q='{}')
```

Is this possible in microsoft graph ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the items contained inside a office365 onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724252/how-to-get-all-the-items-contained-inside-a-office365-onedrive)

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Just as a note, the best way is to use delta api, store files metadata locally and query database using recursive query to get list of files.......

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the correct link is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root/search(q='')
```

Thanks @Marc LaFleur

**2021 edit**: this api unfortunately doesn't return all the files. So I ended up using the sharepoint delta api to sync sharepoint data locally, then I use a mysql query to find all files of a given folder (there is a child <-> parent relation in the files/folder metadata return from the API)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find all of the files recursively of a SharePoint Document Library (which is still a `Drive`), you can apply a filter on the Content type not being a `Folder`. for example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields,driveItem&$filter=fields/ContentType eq 'Document'
```

This will return all of the Documents (i.e.: anything not a folder) recursively. Since the `driveItem` is being expanded, you will have all of the `DriveItem` details needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to list all items with this below :

{drive-root-id} is the /Drive/root "id" value return from :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{site-id}/drive/root
```

Then :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{site-id}/drive/items/{drive-root-id}/children
```