# Get all items names in drive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I need something simple, but spent already a lot of hours on it and didn't succeded yet, I want to get all file names in a given drive (one of the users, I'm logged in as admin) ,I will expand the solution for recursive one by myself, for making stuff simple let's suppose I have only the following files in this structure:

[Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)

```
/root/someFolder/someFile.txt
/root/file2.txt
```

and I want the output:

```
someFile.txt
file2.txt
```

My code is:

```
var res = await GraphClient.Users["user3@myCompanyName.onmicrosoft.com"].Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
foreach (DriveItem p in res.CurrentPage)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

Output:

> someFolder
>
> file2.txt

That's not the output I need

Comment: what is type of `p` and `p.Name`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar `Microsoft.Graph.DriveItem`

Comment: Have you tried using the search functionality to achieve this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756250/1145403

Comment: First of all, your output is 100% correct, because there is a folder. So what you need to do is to see what type the output is, and if it is a folder, you need to do the same request on that folder.

Comment: @Jaques Yha I know, but *how*

Comment: Figure it out. There is a lot of examples. And if you don't know how to take guidance, its probably better if you go and look for free workers somewhere else. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: @LennartStoop The link helped a lot, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior since endpoint `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children` returns one level beneath items only, so to retrieve all the items, sub folder items needs to be explicitly retrieved as demonstrated below:

```
var allItems = new List<DriveItem>();
await GetAllChildren(graphClient.Me.Drive, allItems);    
foreach (var item in allItems)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

where

```
static async Task GetAllChildren(IDriveRequestBuilder drive,List<DriveItem> result, IDriveItemRequestBuilder root = null)
{
    root = root ?? drive.Root;
    var items = await root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
    result.AddRange(items.ToList());
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.Folder != null && item.Folder.ChildCount > 0)
        {
            await GetAllChildren(drive, result, drive.Items[item.Id]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

There is a better way (from performance perspective) to retrieve all drive items metadata via the following endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/list/items?$expand=driveItem
```

> Note: Only a single request is required to retrieve all the items
>   which might be a big advantage over the previous approach

Example

```
var allItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive.List.Items.Request().Expand( i => i.DriveItem).GetAsync();
foreach (var item in allItems)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.DriveItem.Name); //print name
}
```